# How to properly include 'Firebase/Auth' pod for iOS or react-native project?

Tags: firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

Goal: In a react-native project, I'm using `react-native-firebase` v5.6 and because im using Firebase's authentication, I need to include "Firebase/Auth" in the pod file so react-native-firebase's bindings can use it.

Problem: Once `pod "Firebase/Auth"` is added and saved to podfile, and `pod install` is successfully run, the project build fails when compiling RNFirebaseAuth.m. I haven't added any auth related code, just simply installed the pod and clean&ran build. Sidenote, other react-native-firebase setup/integration has been successful to this point.

Failing Error:

```
/path/to/project/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/auth/RNFirebaseAuth.m:1184:36: error: no known class method for selector 'credentialWithProviderID:IDToken:rawNonce:'
    credential = [FIROAuthProvider credentialWithProviderID:@"apple.com" IDToken:authToken rawNonce:authTokenSecret];
```

Have I just missed an installation step or what? How do I fix build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mikehardy on GitHub, react-native-firebase v5.6 has a minor breaking change that enforces the use of firebase pods with at least version 6.13.

I ran `pod update` and that was all that was needed to fix the build